# About monotonicity of power functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the function:
$\large{1\over(x-2)^3}+3$
monotonic?
I understand it is strictly decreasing in its domain, but being discontinous makes it not monotonic. Is this right?
Sorry if this question sounds trivial to you.
Thanks in advance.
Raul

Comment: It's not necessarily the discontinuity that makes it non-monotonic, just the existence of two values $x \leq y$ with $f(x) \not\leq f(y)$. In this case 1 and 3 work. You can have discontinuous functions which jump around but are still monotonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, it's not monotonic.

Let's call the function $f$.

It's domain is $X = \mathbb R \setminus \{2\}$.

It's (strictly) monotonically decreasing on the interval $\left]-\infty, 2\right[$, and on the interval $\left]2, \infty \right[$.

But it's not monotone on its entire domain. You can see that $f(1) = 2$ and $f(3) = 4$, so $f(x)$ **increases** between $x=1$ and $x=3$, which destroys any hope of it being monotonically decreasing everywhere on its domain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! Now I dare to ask if we can accept in general that this type of functions: $f(x)={a\over(x-d)^n}+e$ are non-monotonic. I understand they can be decreasing or increasing depending on the sign of "a" and if "n" is even or odd.

Comment: Let's assume that $a>0$. If $n$ is odd, the behaviour is more-or-less the same as in your specific example. If $n$ is even, then the function will be increasing on $\left]-\infty, d\right[$ and decreasing on $\left]d, \infty\right[$, so not even close to monotonic. The case $a<0$ can be analyzed in a similar way.